# Delete many records on a django queryset returns error

Tags: python, django, delete-row

I'm trying to delete more than 10000 records with a delete applied on a Django filter :

```
EntityNew.objects.filter(dico=US).delete()
```

but it returns the following error:

```
DatabaseError: ('07009', '[07009] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid descriptor index (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

It appears that the same command works if I narrow down the number of rows returned by the filter. Example:

```
EntityNew.objects.filter(dico=US,id<100).delete()
```

Is there a limit on a delete command?

Comment: There is NO limit on the delete command in Django (we regularly delete 10's of thousands of records). BUT a quick google of the '07009' error reveals quite a number of people talking about what people seem to be saying is some sort of bug. It's not clear to me whether the bug is in FreeTDS or in SQL Server (although there are some hot fixes referred to).